# How to play flv in UWP APP with C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, flv

I want to use MediaPlayer class to play .flv file int UWP app. Here are some test code is't very easy, but it doesn't work. If I play .mp4 file, it's OK, what have to do to play .flv file?

```
namespace mediaPlayer
{
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {
    private MediaPlayer player = null;

     public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("http://10.160.72.72/vod/1987.flv "));
        player = mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer;
        player.Play();
    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Pause();
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. `MediaPlayer` can't play `.flv` format. Read this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0b1d2d0d-f7ba-4a9e-80bb-d67059453c33/play-mpegflv-files-im-media-element):

I would suggest you convert it to different format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx

One possible way is this [Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/). Haven't tried it out, but it should play `.flv` format.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank for your help! is there any way to play .flv file in UWP app with c#?

Comment: Check my updated answer. If it helps, tag this as an answer, so it can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FFMpegInterop](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop). It isn't easy to set up but the Github page for it and articles online could help you get it up and running, I used it for a project in the past and it has worked for me.